# Error in URDF file

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I try to build urdf model robot. End I have error message:

```
Invalid parameter "name" while expanding macro "bioloid_F10"
```

I use 2 files, head.xacro and head_hardware.xacro.

In head.xacro:

```
<include filename="$(find robot_description)/urdf/head_hardware.xacro" />

    <bioloid_F10 parent="bioloid_F4_head_10" name="head_tilt_bracket">
       <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </bioloid_F10_fixed>
```

In head_hardware.xacro

```
<macro name="bioloid_F10" params="parent number x_loc y_loc z_loc">
```

What is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127541/error-in-urdf-file/) by [seredin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8936/seredin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-02-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Name is not a parameter in your macro. The parameters in the macro must match the ones you pass into the usage of the macro.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4